# When is it necessary to explicitly place attributes on controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a new MVC 4 project. I created a custom action filter and inherited from ActionFilterAttribute. I created an override for OnActionExecuting(). At the moment, it doesn't do much; it just outputs a message to the output window. Last, I registered the action filter in RegisterGlobalFilters(), found in FilterConfig.cs.

When I run the application the application, the breakpoint gets hit. This is good. However, I didn't add any attributes to any controllers. Is this behavior correct? When do I need to add attributes to my controllers? How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegisterGlobalFilters is applicable to all controllers.

You may want to add specific attributes to specific controllers in some cases. For example, a certain controller may require a certain role using `[Authorize (Roles="group1")]` whereas all others do not. Adding the attribute to that controller only will give you this functionality.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I confirmed your answer through a series of tests: commenting out the registration line in FilterConfig and adding an attribute to my controller class, commenting out both, commenting out the attribute and uncommenting the registration.

Comment: @user1469655 Then you could always mark this question as answered ;)